# Free-form dictionary?

Tags: discussion

Is there a program/website that allows me to input text to describe an idea and find the word for it? I use The Sage and Lingoes but they're not ideal.

For instance, a little while ago I asked Google for a 'word for repeating received ideas' and settled on 'stereotypical'.

Comment: Onelook Reverse Dictionary might help: http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574

Comment: Really? Other than how clearly you put the question, how would Google fail at that (other search engines are available)

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Google is pretty sophisticated but I imagine OP would prefer a database strictly of words and definitions. The example search, for example, could return results that include 'word', 'repeating' and 'ideas'—like articles about speech. This could be helpful but isn't precisely what the searcher is looking for

Comment: Oh… OK. By the way, doesn't 'stereotypical' describe the idea? Wouldn't a 'word for repeating received ideas' be something like 'reinforcing' 'reinforcement'?

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is probably the [Words and Linguistics](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/WordsAndLinguistics.html) section of the [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) search engine.

This has a number of ways of entering searches and can return words matching requirements.
I find this to be an excellent resource.

Answer (score 2):

[OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/) lets you perform [reverse lookups](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml). This means that you can type words that you expect to be part of the definition of a term, and terms whose definition contains those words will be listed in order of match quality.

This can be used in a way that's pretty close in practice to just typing a description of the word you're seeking, and the site actually encourages using it that way ("this tool lets you describe a concept and get back a list of words and phrases related to that concept").

However, you must not expect any actual understanding of "concept": no [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) is involved, which could narrow down the results considerably but also fail to yield anything meaningful in a majority of cases, and would also be much more difficult to implement. This is ultimately just an unusual but simple type of dictionary search.